# Filter tweet keywords

Tags: twitter, twython

I'm trying to filer certain words with Twython before retweeting. I can't figure out a way to get it to work and instead of filtering out certain words, it's adding those words to the ones to retweet. Here is my code:

```
    naughty_words = ["",'"Sign up"', "kindle", "read", "book", "amzn", "amazon"]
    good_words = ["Giveaway", ""]

    filter = "OR".join(good_words)
    blacklist = "-".join(naughty_words)
    keywords = filter + blacklist

    search_results = twitter.search(q="keywords", count= 5)
    try:
        for tweet in search_results["statuses"]:
            twitter.retweet(id = tweet["id_str"])
            time.sleep(15)

    except TwythonError as e:
            print e
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues that I see, fix those and see if it fixes your problem.

1) `keywords` isn't functioning as expected. From your code now I get `GiveawaySign up -kindle -read -book -amzn -amazon`. This is because `good_words` is a 1 element list, so the `.join` isn't working as expected.

2) The way "Sign Up" is done will show up as "Sign" AND "up" that's more likely the problem.

Try the following:

```
naughty_words = ["",'"Sign up"', "kindle", "read", "book", "amzn", "amazon"]
good_words = ["Giveaway", ""]
```

Also, remove the space after `OR` and keep the one before.

**Edit**

Change your `filter` and `blacklist` to:

```
filter = "".join(good_words)
blacklist = " -".join(naughty_words)
```

Since you only have one word in `good_words` there's not need for the `OR`. You should get:

`Giveaway -"Sign up" -kindle -read -book -amzn -amazon`

Comment: That didn't fix anything at all. I still have the same problem :'(.

Comment: `Giveaway OR -"Sign up" -kindle -read -book -amzn -amazon` is from the one I provided. `GiveawaySign up -kindle -read -book -amzn -amazon` is from your printout of `keywords`. The output is quite different at the beginning to comply with [Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) make sure it's update correctly. I ran it and worked fine for me.

Comment: Where do I put that stuff? I updated the question above to comply with my changes. Could you tell me where I should change things specifically? (I'm new to this stuff")